Example in finite element method tutorial does not work
I am trying to run this example for the finite element method. Here is the code copied from the tutorial.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

tvars = {T[x, y], {x, y}};
pars = <|"MassDensity" -> \[Rho], "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Cp, 
   "ThermalConductivity" -> k*IdentityMatrix[2], 
   "HeatConvectionVelocity" -> {u[x, y], v[x, y]}|>;
SteadyHeatModel = HeatTransferPDEComponent[tvars, pars]

CFDModel =
    {\[Rho]  {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
        Inactive[Div][(-\[Mu] Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
    
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}], Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], \[Rho]  {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + Inactive[Div][(-\[Mu] Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}], Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], 
   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}], Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] +   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]};
{Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y]} = {0, \[Alpha]*g*\[Rho]*(T[x, y] - Subscript[T, in])};

Subscript[\[Rho], water] = 
  QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Water", "Density"]];
Subscript[k, water] = 
  QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Water", "ThermalConductivity"]];
Subscript[\[Mu], water] = 
  QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Water", "Viscosity"]];
Subscript[Cp, water] = 
  QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Water", "IsobaricHeatCapacity"]];

w = 0.005;
h = 0.045;
r = 0.0025;

\[CapitalOmega] = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {w, h}], 
   RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0.015}, r], Disk[{0, 0.03}, r]]];

mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 5*10^-4}];

wire1 = x^2 + (y - 0.015)^2 <= r^2;
wire2 = x^2 + (y - 0.03)^2 <= r^2;
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp] = {HeatTemperatureCondition[y == 0, tvars, 
    pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> Subscript[T, in]|>], 
   HeatTemperatureCondition[wire1 || wire2, tvars, 
    pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> Subscript[T, wire]|>]};

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], inlet] = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == Subscript[v, in]}, y == 0];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, wire1 || wire2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], outlet] = DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, y == h];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], sym] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 || x == w];

bcs = {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], inlet], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], outlet], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], sym], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp]};

parameters = {\[Rho] -> Subscript[\[Rho], water], 
   k -> Subscript[k, water], \[Mu] -> Subscript[\[Mu], water], 
   Cp -> Subscript[Cp, water], \[Alpha] -> 1.8*10^-4, 
   Subscript[v, in] -> 5*10^-3, g -> 9.81, Subscript[T, in] -> 300, 
   Subscript[T, wire] -> 375};

pde = {CFDModel == {Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y], 0}, SteadyHeatModel == 0, bcs} /. parameters;

measure = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   MaxMemoryUsed[{ufun, vfun, pfun, Tfun} = 
      NDSolveValue[pde, {u, v, p, T}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
       Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}},
        "InitialSeeding" -> {u[x, y] == 0, 
          v[x, y] == Subscript[v, in], p[x, y] == 0, 
          T[x, y] == Subscript[T, in]} /. parameters]]/(1024.^2)];
Print["Time -> ", measure[[1]], "\nMemory -> ", measure[[2]]]

However, this example does not work in version 13.3.1.0 and gives the following errors:

FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached.


NDSolveValue::fempsf: PDESolve could not find a solution.


Set: Lists {ufun,vfun,pfun,Tfun} and NDSolveValue...

Processor Type: Intel-i9 x86-64
My system info:
 {" Version", "13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"}

Questions:

Can anyone please help debug the code or point out the issues?

By running the example, I want to test if one can change "ThermalConductivity" -> k*IdentityMatrix[2] to "ThermalConductivity" -> k, because in other tutorials I see a remark about thermal conductivity: "For numeric values, the "ThermalConductivity" is automatically converted to a matrix of proper dimensions". Thus, I expected that *IdentityMatrix[2] is redundant.

I also want to test if one can change <= in wire1 = x^2 + (y - 0.015)^2 <= r^2; wire2 = x^2 + (y - 0.03)^2 <= r^2; to =, because the temperature b.c. HeatTemperatureCondition for wire1 || wire2 is essentially applied to the surface (=) of the wires instead of the surface plus its interior (<=).


Thank you very much!

Do you have an ARM Mac? Try to run this under Rosetta and see if that fixes the problem.

@user21 I only have a Dell laptop and a desktop, which run Win11 and Win10 respectively. I'm curious about which commands or functions are incompatible with Win OS in this code?

When I run your code I get the same convergence error as you did. However, the code in the documentation works just fine (checked with version 13.3, Linux, Intel CPU) So I suspect you either made a copy - past error or changed some parameters such that the model no longer converges. If you knowingly did this, I suggest to point that out in the post, else copy the code again.

Thank you@user21, I did not change anything in the code, but just copy & past from the doc of version 13.3.1.0, as indicated in the title and text of the post.

OK, just to double check if you run the example in the documentation (no copy and paste to new notebook) you get the same error, is that correct?

@user21, for version 13.3.1.0 accessible to my school, we only have web documentation. So I just click (copy to clipboard) and paste it to a fresh notebook without any modification.

Can anyone else with a Windows machine reproduce the issue in the tutorial notebook, not the version from here? Again, when I run your code that you have pasted here I do get the same error, but I do not get the error if I run the notebook from the documentation. To me that suggests that something went wrong from copying the version from the (web) documentation to the notebook.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I’m voting to close this question because you claim in the subject that: "Example in finite element method tutorial does not work" but no one was able to reproduce that in the actual notebook, It is very likely that the issues you see come from a copy / past error or some modification you made.
